# Convert SQLreader to float?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been trying to retrieve the loan amount and wanted it to be float. However, the loanAmount returns me a value of 0.0. btw the sql statement only return one value. please help?

```
SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd4.Connection = conn;
        cmd4.CommandText = "SELECT loanAmount FROM LoanPortfolio WHERE custID='" + custIDs + "' AND loanType LIKE 'Personal Loan'";
        conn.Open();
        float loanAmount = 0.0F;
        SqlDataReader amountLoan = cmd4.ExecuteReader();
        while (amountLoan.Read())
        {
            loanAmount = float.Parse(amountLoan.ToString());
            break;
        }
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' to type 'System.IConvertible'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928388/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-data-sqlclient-sqldatareader-to-type-sys)

Answer (score 4):

If you are selecting a single value used ExecuteScalar() instead:

```
float loanAmount = Convert.ToFloat(cmd4.ExecuteScalar());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not for a SELECT statmenet, this requires a different SQL.

Comment: @HenkHolterman `ExecuteScalar` will work on a select statement, it just takes the first column of the first row.

Comment: Theres no "Convert.ToFloat"

Comment: Is the data type in the database float? if so then do `float loanAmount = (float)cmd4.ExecuteScalar();`  Otherwise you can try `float loanAmount = float.Parse(cmd4.ExecuteScalar().ToString());`

Answer (score 1):

> btw the sql statement only return one value

You still need to specify the column:

```
 loanAmount = float.Parse(amountLoan[0].ToString());
```

There exist better ways to get that value, depends on column type etc.

Comment: I'd favour `amountLoan.GetFloat(0)` if the sql type being returned is actually a float.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - but the db type is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

From the pluralized variable name (`custIDs`), I assume that you are passing in multiple ids and that you inserted the `break` for debugging / test purposes. Modify your command text to:

```
cmd4.CommandText = "SELECT loanAmount FROM LoanPortfolio WHERE custID IN (" + custIDs + ") AND loanType LIKE 'Personal Loan'";
```

Make sure that `custId` is a coma separated values string of customer ids.
You should select the first column in the reader:

```
float.Parse(amountLoan[0].ToString())
```

or use the [SqlDataReader.GetFloat method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getfloat.aspx).

Also, you need to store the return values in some sort of collection (array, list etc.). right now, even if the query returns multiple records, you will only fetch the last record's value.

Comment: I'd favour `amountLoan.GetFloat(0)` if the sql type being returned is actually a float.

Comment: Actually he isn't selecting anything, but if he corrects his data reader access he'd be selecting the first value and then `break`ing out.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, I missed that `break`. It's even more catastrophic than it seemed to me on the first impression :)